# ¿Cómo hago para que me pueda funcionar esta línea de código en mi SweetAlert2?

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert2

```
if (result.isConfirmed) {
            window.location.href="eliminar categoria.php? codigo=".$fila['codigo']."";
        }
```

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y se que no debo mezclar " con ' pero de verdad no se me ocurre alguna otra manera de formularlo. :(

esta es la página donde se encuentra la lista

```
<?php
$queto= "SELECT * FROM categorias";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion, $queto);

echo "<table class='table table-hover text-center'>
<tr>
<td class='text-center'><strong>Código</strong></td>
<td class='text-center'><strong>Nombre<strong></td>
<td class='text-center'><strong>Editar<strong></td>
<td class='text-center'><strong>Eliminar<strong></td>
</tr>";
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $fila['codigo']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $fila['nombre']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-success btn-raised btn-xs' href='actualizar categoria.php? codigo=".$fila['codigo']." '>
        <i class='zmdi zmdi-refresh'></i></td>";
        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-xs eliminarcategoria' href='#!'>
        <i class='zmdi zmdi-delete'></i></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";


 ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola. En primer lugar no entiendo por qué tienes unas rutas con espacios entre medio (eliminar categoria.php? codigo=.....) Pon todo junto. Y ya en segundo lugar, no sé si ambos fragmentos de código pertenecen al mismo archivo. Pero te explico lo que yo haría: En cada td de la tabla colocaría un botón o texto clickeable, y una vez clickeado abriría la ventana SweetAlert2. Y por el código me redirigiría al link que hace algo. Usa el evento onclick.

Comment: Otro detalle, mezclar " con ' está bien. Uno va afuera y el otro adentro. Te aconsejo que el " vaya afuera, el ' dentro y no concatenes con los puntos. Hay varias formas de concatenar. Yo concateno así y me resulta más legible: "eliminar_categoria.php?codigo={$fila['codigo']}"; (Esas llaves {} se pueden obviar e igual resulta, solo que me gusta colocarlas). Y, esa forma de concatenar solo funciona si las " van afuera, con ' no resulta.